# VB Date picker format confused when saving to sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, datepicker, visual-studio-2015

I have been using date pickers for users to select a short date (UK format), the program grabs the datepicker.text and saves that as a string (I know :) bear with me) to an sql database.

When I needed to do something I got the values, converted to dates and compared. No problem!

I got to a problem area which was comparing the stored dates with date pickers on a form, in the actual query in the sqlcommand command text. it obviously wont compare a date with a string.

so I went and changed my database to store the date field as a date not a string.

Since then I have been having issues grabbing any dates, as the ones I save from the datepickers into the SQL database are for some reason turned into US Dates so when i extract them they are then backwards with the month and day.

and if I save say 20/11/2015 it errors as it cant save the date as its too large on the month US style

I extremely tempted to go back to storing dates as strings as that actually works, but would rather do it properly

Does anyone have any suggestions or has done any workarounds for this issue.I would most like to hear them

many thanks

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are doing something like `Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM  [Table]  WHERE DateColumn = '" & YourDate.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY") & "';"` and not using [strongly typed parameters](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). It is of course impossible to say what is wrong with your code if you don't share it... Can you update your question with the code you are using so that we can propose some fixes?

Comment: HI there, here is the insert code  "INSERT INTO tblTime (timeRef, timeDate) VALUES('" + txtReference.Text + "', '" + CDate(dteTimeDate.Text) + "')" this just gives an error if the date is over the 12th of any month as it looks at it like a US date

Comment: Can you also post the VB code you are using to the question. You definitely need to use parameterised queries, but I need to see how you are currently connecting to the database in order to suggest an alternative. I am not sure if you are using VBA (as in the tag) or VB.NET which would be more likely when using Visual Studio and DatePickers. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the code into the question.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for replies, yes you are right it is vb.net i have changed tag.  I think its just ideas on how to get the uk date in to sql, as with the insert query above i cant insert a uk date, if i then `SELECT * FROM tblTime , sqlCon ` i get the US date back and it doesn't match any output from my datepickers which output uk shortdates, do i really have to start chopping up the datepicker output and reassemble in US format to get it to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are concatenating strings to form your SQL statement, the code sample you have given is:

```
"INSERT INTO tblTime (timeRef, timeDate) VALUES('" + txtReference.Text + "', '" + CDate(dteTimeDate.Text) + "')"
```

This will give you conversion and truncation issues (that you are experiencing), or worse, will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. You should **ALWAYS** use parameterised queries where possible.

You haven't given much indication of what you are currently using, so I will just give a generic example connecting to a SQL Server database and using SqlCommand to execute an insert statement:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT tblTime (timeRef, timeDate) VALUES (@timeRef, @timeDate);"

Using connection As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@timeRef", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtReference.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@timeDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dteTimeDate.Value
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Using
End Using
```

<sub>*N.B. I haven't used VB.NET in a while so please forgive any slight syntax errors, hopefully the gist is good enough to get started*</sub>

Since you explicitly tell SQL Server that the parameter `@timeDate` is of `DateTime` type, then there is no ambiguity about the format, you don't need to worry about regional variations, or whether 01/02/2015 is the 1st of January, or the 2nd February.

Comment: HI gareth, many thanks indeed , no worries as you may guess I'm still learning myself. I will give this a go and see what i can come up with - I think avoiding SQl injection would be good as well :) i had better get in the habit of using parameters